# Standardized "Moderation" Commenting

Tags: discussion, comments

I spent quite some time in the last few days watching other people "moderate" SO, by giving hints to the users through comments mostly.

Is there a set of standard comments that can be used? I think most people I've seen had come up with their own way of saying things like: "post some code", "the problem is not in the code you posted", "work on your accept rate", etc...

For example, a bit earlier a saw a nice comment from Robᵩ:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow. The lines that you have shown us look ok. I
>   presume the problem is in the lines that you haven't shown us. Please
>   reduce your original program to the smallest possible program that
>   still demonstrates the error, and copy-paste that program into your
>   question. See sscce.org for more details.

Would there be some interest in making, say, a Firefox plugin with pre-made answers to accelerate the process and standardize the feedback given to newer users?

**Edit:** I saw the script suggested [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) but this doesn't seem to use "standardized" comments coming from the leading actors of the community. It would be pretty easy to `fork` and make it use a set of standardized answers stored on github so that everybody can give consistent answers.

Comment: See http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: Ahh excellent, it should be more advertised I guess :)

Comment: While I believe this would be true for properly crafted questions... but that's rarely the case on SO :)

Comment: @jonsca, you should put that as an answer.

Comment: @jonsca ok, I played with it a little, and while interesting, it doesn't cover a lot of the common topics I see, and since everybody can create their own snippets to include, it isn't "standardized" much

Comment: Incidentally; the "increase your accept rate" comments are something you should *not* do.

Comment: @AndrewBarber not even to users with 0% accept rate that don't speak English as their main language and probably didn't understand that the site works by accepting answers?

Comment: @emartel a one-time reminder is okay, not repeated comments on the same

Answer (score 4):

There is a script available for such purposes on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

I think the sentiment is that making such a utility part of the Stack Exchange interface would potentially tempt users (both well meaning and not) to simply insert a pro-forma comment and move on.  While there is some specificity to those in the script ("Welcome to X Site!", etc), new users could and ought to benefit from advice that's even more tailored to the situation.

Comment: Converted from comments above.

Comment: It's debatable, but there are certain users on the network that should be banned from leaving any comment other than what's in the pro forma comment tool. ;)  It might be better to have some canned responses instead of some of the rude/NC comments that some users leave. ;)  However, at the same time, I agree that personalized comments, if written gracefully, can have a positive impact on users.